Difference between one-party state and coalition state
When one party has a full control over the state ignoring opinions of others it is usually called a dictatorship. But when two or more parties form a so-called "coalition" and actually do the same thing, it is decided a democracy.
The difference between these systems could lie in the compromises that are made during the decision-making, but in practice we mostly see ultimatums like "agree with it or we leave the coalition" or bargains "do what we want today and tomorrow we will do what you want".
Why no one calls coalition governments a "dictatorship"?

I feel that you're comparing apples and frogs. Dictatorships don't have free & fair elections; democracies do. A democracy can have a single-party government (as is common in the UK), or a coalition (as is common in Germany); either way, the government has control of the state (to varying degrees), until either a later election removes them, or politics within or between parties causes them to fracture. Besides elections, democracies also tend to have multiple (legal) parties, whereas dictatorships don't.

No one calls the US a dictatorship when one party has the majority in the supreme court, congress and control of the white house, at least I have never heard that said.

Out of curiosity OP, have you ever followed coalition formation discussions in countries where they're common? They often involve a different set of parties after each election (though some parties can feature more commonly), which involve a lot of debate to even find functional common ground for a legislative agenda (Belgium is famous for taking 2 years recently), and its pretty common for coalitions to fall apart before the next election is even due, triggering early elections. This is because each has a different agenda, which causes them to start diverging again as events occur.

@JoeW Yes, and this is exactly the question - "why is so?" From the answer it is clear that in Western democracies "we are fine as long as we can have a new tyrant every N years".

Based on your latest comment it seems to be an attempt so smear countries where one party is more supported then the other during an election cycle. Just because one party has more support at a time doesn't mean that there is a tyrant in power and that it is a dictatorship.

@JoeW No. I'm just trying to find out what other people think about this and what their reasons are for having a different POV than mine. In my opinion, if someone (an individual or a group of people) can do something while completely ignoring others, that's tyranny. So when United Russia deputies walk out of the Duma before voting on a bill proposed by the opposition, leaving it no chance, that's tyranny. When Republican majority block a Democrat bill just because it's from the Democrats... that's tyranny too.

But you seem to be ignoring the idea that it is perfectly possible and valid for one party or a group of parties to take power for a bit before it is transferred to  a different party or group of parties. It is something that happens all the time in a democracy.

@JoeW Whenever I look I see a problem with "different party or group". In USA two parties ping-ponging the absolute power to each other over and over again, in Germany we have a little more, but most of them are always melt into the coalition ruled by two so actually nothing changes at all.

@user13964273 The issue is that you'll end up in a tyranny regardless, by your definitions. The question is just how often you switch up who is in charge. The main benefits of democracy are that the tyrant in question will at least roughly align with what the people prefer, and that there's a mechanism aside from bloody revolution for getting rid of them when people no longer prefer them. Aside from that there are constitutions in order to limit how much power said tyrant can wield.

If you have an idea for how to create a system where this is not the case feel free to create a post/comment sharing it for discussion. That said, please keep in mind the obvious question of "how does this stop someone who doesn't want to play nice." The concept of enlightened rule by people who truly wish the best for the people is great, right up until you see what happens when one of those people gets more interesting in what's best for them, or when people start disagreeing on what is best for the people, or their vision of what is best stops aligning with what the people themselves want.

The issue is never a single party being in control but what they do to maintain power.

The difference between a functioning democracy according to Western understanding and a one-party state is that while in a democracy the parties are on equal footing, in a one-party dictatorship there are mechanism (officially or inofficially) which ensure that "The Party" remains in charge and other parties either don't exist or are not a political threat to "The Party".
A good example of an official one-party state is the People's Republic of China, where Article 1 of the constitution states that:

The socialist system is the basic system of the People's Republic of China. The leadership of the Communist Party of China is the defining feature of socialism with Chinese characteristics. Sabotage of the socialist system by any organization or individual is prohibited.

That means that it is unconstitutional in China for any serious threat to the authority of the Communist Party of China to exist. The result is that any political organization must be subservient to the CCP, or finds itself on the wrong side of the law.
An example of an unofficial one-party state could be the Russian Federation, where elections are free and equal in theory, but any political leaders who become a serious threat to the party United Russia and its agenda routinely just happen to end up in prison, in exile or dead.
This is different from a democracy according to Western understanding, in which a party might temporarily rule (alone or with one or more coalition partners), but only until the next election. Then it will find itself in a fair competition for the favor of the voters and might lose its position to another party.
The main problem with coalition governments is that while the smaller parties depend on the larger party to get their policies implemented, so is the larger party dependent on the smaller parties. So coalitions are in a permanent state of mutually assured destruction. If they can't keep making compromises with each other, then they risk losing all the power they together hold as a coalition government. This is visible in Germany right now, where the 3-party coalition between SPD, Greens and FDP was just dissolved. The result is that the chancellor just became a "lame duck", because he can no longer rely on a majority in parliament to get anything done. Which leaves him no other option than to trigger a snap-election, get a new parliament elected and (hopefully) find a new government coalition within the new parliament composition... or lose the job of chancellor to someone else who can.

This is a good answer but still it doesn't explain why compromises can be made only inside of a coalition. Do parties really are so stiff that they are unable to find a compromise for every individual decision among whole parliament without any opinion being ignored?

@user13964273 Your original question was to explain why a democratically elected coalition government is not a dictatorship. Which I answered: Because they are democratically elected and can be democratically un-elected. If you would like to know why it is so rare in parliamentary democracies to have minority governments without an official coalition partner, and why Olaf Scholz would rather risk his job in a snap election (he will probably lose) than even give it a try, then that might be enough material for a new question.

@user13964273 The issue is that if you're the largest minority party you still need to convince a majority to vote to confirm your leader as prime minister (or at least not hold an immediate vote of no confidence). Forming a coalition means giving other parties with relatively similar goals to your own a stake in government so they won't start a no-confidence vote. That doesn't mean that they're required to stick together for the rest of the term (and they often don't), but it provides far more stability and ease of governance than doing the horse trading every time a vote comes up.

@kenod I know that I'm naive but I hope that parties are running into the parliament because their goal is a good for people of the country, not an ego of their leaders so choosing of a prime minister is a logical arguing "A is better than B because of experience, education, results in the past, etc", not just "A is ours, B is theirs, let's start the fight in a steel cage until there will be only one".

@user13964273 The thing is that each party runs for parliament because they think they know what is best, and being PM is the position that lets you put your view into action the best, with the other ministerial slots letting you influence other, more specific areas. Parties are willing to accept a PM from a different party, but providing direct support normally requires an agreement to support their plans too, to some extend, which can be formalized by giving them the ministerial positions they need. For example, getting the farmer party support by giving them the ministry of agriculture.

Essentially, any party campaigns based on what they believe is best for the country (ideally), and how many votes they get is how many people agree with them. If the largest party doesn't have a majority that means a lot of people agree with them, but not the majority. If they can form a coalition that means enough other people agreed with viewpoints compatible with theirs. If they can't get a majority coalition, but a number of smaller parties can, that means more people agreed with those combined viewpoints, and therefore they should run the government, since they clearly have more support.

Mainly, because in democracies, when one "take it or leave it" offer is refused, the options for the other party is to either find another willing partner to form a government, or to head to new elections.
In dictatorships, "take it or leave it" (if it is ever uttered) is understood to "agree with me or face prison, execution, or worse."
Apart from that minor, frivolous detail, democracies are characterized by the "market of ideas". Political parties want to offer their voters something (promises, ideas, brand) that distinguish them from others. Which is one of the reasons of tensions in coalition government, each party must show to its base that it is fulfilling its promises to the maximum extent so there is an incentive to try to not to align too much with the other parties.
That makes coalition governments not that uniform (as opposed of a dictatorship) and prone to changes in composition as the balance of power and votes change. In a democracy, if there is a coalition government but then one of the members of the coalition gets enough votes to govern alone, then it will typically expel the other party from power (at best, giving the other party a consultive role if there is interest in keeping a relationship).
And of course, in a democracy the ruling coalition can just be voted out at the next election. That is another of those small details that characterize democracy.
In addition, political parties in democracy are democratic themselves. So, even if the parties stay in government for a long time, internal dynamics in the parties may mean significant changes in policies, driven by internal support from the base.
